# Should ASP.NET v2 IIS server extension be missing after .NET 4 is installed?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, asp.net, wcf

I'm having a ton of issues when my ASP.NET sites are using version 2.  For example, all my SVC and ASPX files return "file not found".  Also when I use IISMgr and navigate to:

ServerName 
..... Web Service Extensions

I notice that no ASP.NET v2 is present. I tried aspnet_regiis but no luck.  Any ideas?

[image]

**UPDATE**

Running aspnet_regiis.exe – i seemed to now have worked. But I'm still having issues with WCF. I just tried reinstalling WCF using ServiceModelReg -i and I get this in the event log

[image]

Also, this is what ServiceModelReg -ls looks like (note no Web Host Script Mappings exist)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not normal; you should have three ASP.NET externsions there: 1.1, 2.0 and 4.0.

Which aspet_regiis did you try? The 2.0 one or the 4.0 one?

Is this a x86 or x64 server?

For x86, run `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir`.

For x64, run `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir`.

Comment: AWESOME, That worked!  It's back.  I just ran ServiceModelReg to reinstall WCF, and it says I have no Web Host Script Mappings.  Does that make sense?

Comment: The command I used was: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation>ServiceModelReg.exe -lv

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't mark this as the answer?

Comment: WCF is still broken, but I can create a new one for that...